# File Upload Permission denied Godaddy Shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, file-permissions

I have a web application on godaddy shared hosting. Its a asp.net application. Everything working fine but when I upload some file it gives an error "Access to the path 'PATH' is denied."

I tried several ways like giving full permission to the folder in which I am uploading the file from godaddy control panel.

I also saw this post and tried to follow he said  : http://forums.asp.net/t/1052417.aspx/1

But no help.

Can anyone suggest me whats wrong there. Its under IIS 7.

Comment: Please suggest something..This should be a common problem and I believe most of us must have faced it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this: 
[Source](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/access-to-the-path-is-denied-2/) - [2](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/access-to-the-path-is-denied/)

“Setting Directory Permissions with Windows Hosting Accounts”

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6481

*You should ask your hosting provider for access permissions if it doesn't solve your problem.*

Ref: 
[Removing Web Access to Directories on a Windows Hosting Account](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3989/removing-web-access-to-directories-on-a-windows-hosting-account)

> Removing the "Anonymous Access" IIS Setting for that directory. The
>   result of removing this permission is that you can only access that
>   directory from with your hosting account or via FTP. You will not be
>   able to access the directory through any Web browser, regardless of
>   whether you are knowledgeable of the hosting account user name and
>   password.

Comment: Hi Niranjan, thanks for the reply. I already have gone through these links and the file permission is set as READ/WRITE in godaddy admin panel. The file upload through FTP is working but when I upload the file using my code, it fails completely. I tried to add the impersonate setting as per this link "http://forums.asp.net/t/1052417.aspx/1" in the web config but still no luck. My files are not on root folder. I have added a folder and I am trying to store the files into this folder.

Comment: as per the support team of the godaddy, Select permissions for the selected files: `Write — Applications can write to this directory.` then it should work..

Comment: Hi Niranjan, thanks for reply and helping me in this issue. I have checked the Anonymous access is already given. So I don't know what else should I do. Is there anything I can do? Please suggest.

Answer (score 17):

1. Open "File Manager"
2. Navigate to folder and hover over it
3. Click little "down" arrow towards right edge of "Name" column (see image)
4. Click "Change Permissions"
5. Select user (you'll most likely want to use "Plesk IIS Worker Process Identity Account" if you're doing file uploads through your site) and set permissions as needed

[image]

Comment: This works. I'd also like to add that you need to grant WRITE permission to the "Application pool group" user name.

Comment: And I got "Operation Not Permitted", it is quite annoying!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
    protected void BindGrid()
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/images/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = files;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
            BindGrid();
        }
        else //enter code here
        {
            Response.Write("Please select file to upload");
        }
    }
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
    protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        File.Delete(filePath);
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```