# Access to path is denied when trying to upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Access to the path `D:\Hosting\10983309\html\sunithahome\images\GallerySunithaHA\IMG_7162.jpg` is denied.
I have find this error when I try to upload an Image in GallerySunitha Folder.

How can I solve this problem?

```
if (FileUploadGlry1.HasFile)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadGlry1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUploadGlry1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/GallerySunithaHA/" + FileName));
        con.Open();
        query = "insert into Gallery(ImageName,Caption,ImagePath) values(@Iname,@Cap,@Ipath)";
        Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Iname", FileName);
        Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ipath", "~/images/GallerySunithaHA/" + FileName);
        Sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cap", TextBoxGalleryCaption1.Text);
        Sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        PanelViewImage.Visible = true;
        con.Close();
        TextBoxGalleryCaption1.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Show some code of uploading.

Comment: actually it is working fine in localhost but the error occurred after hosting it in godaddy

Comment: Permission issue that should be dealt directly with godaddy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tt seems you are having problem after hosting your web application on godaddy
you need to give read-write rights to foler `images` to save file in folder

**you need to use GoDaddy's configuation panel to grant write access to that folder.**

for more info  [File Upload Permission denied Godaddy Shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10750678/1460657)

Comment: Thaks you Guys Setting Permission On Godday Solved My Problem