# Upload my files into folder using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload my files into folder like

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/admin_file/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

here my folder name admin_file.

```
protected void BindGrid() {
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/admin_file/"));
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = files;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/admin_file/") + FileUpload1.FileName);
        BindGrid();
    }
    else
    {
        //Response.Write("Please select file to upload");
        string message = "alert('Please select file to upload!')";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
    }

}
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    File.Delete(filePath);
    string message = "alert('Deleted Successfully!')";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
    BindGrid();
}
```

This program execute successfully in local system. When I publish this program to GODADDY not support so anybody tell how to give this path

otherwise send mail pramadivi@gmail.com

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Sounds like a directory permission issue with Godaddy. Check out this post for details on how to change the privacy settings on your admin_file directory... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749880/file-upload-permission-denied-godaddy-shared-hosting

Answer (score 0):

Read this troubleshooting [article](https://in.godaddy.com/help/set-directory-permissions-windows-6481) and follow according to it.

its better practice to use Path.Combine when concatenating folder+file name

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToFolder, fileName));
```